# Equivalence of 0 and 0.0

Tags: arithmetic

Is the whole number $0$ equal or unequal to the decimal number $0.0$, which can also represented as the mixed number $0 \frac{0}{10}$?

Please explain the reasons for the equality or inequality.

Comment: Why would you think they are unequal?

Comment: I can't get MathJax to work in the title. Can someone fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by  "mixed number"? It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: Why does this have the differential equations tag?

Comment: If we convert the number "a.b" from decimal format to power format we get $a*10^0+b*10^{-1}$ so $0.0$ means $a=b=0$  so its $0*10^0+0*10^{-1}=0$

Comment: @William [Google it.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:%22mixed+number%22)

Comment: @Peanut: First, that's a fairly rude response to an innocent question. Second, I googled it as you requested and, as I expected, decimal representations are not what people refer to as "mixed numbers". "Mixed number" is the terminology used when a number is written in the form $a\frac{b}{c}$ and the notation is taken to mean $\frac{ac+b}{c}.$ Finally, you have failed to explain why this question has the "differential-equations" tag.

Comment: @DianFishekqiuI think  you should post this as an answer

Comment: @Peanut And second , 0.0 is not a mixed number (as defined in  the pages your google search returns)

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by the symbols you write.

Comment: 0.0 = 0 + 0/10.  As 0/10 =0, 0.0 =0+0 =0.  They are equal.  Btw "mixed number" is the wrong term for decimal.

Comment: Why they are equal? Because we define them to be so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ordinary mathematics, all representations of 0 are equivalent: $0=0.0=+0=-0$ and so on.

In computer programming, however, 0 may be different from 0.0, in that the former is an *integer* while the latter is a *decimal* (which may be floating-point or arbitrary precision). With the finite space we have to store a number, what is represented by decimal 0.0 may not actually be 0, but rather too small to represent with the precision given. Loss of significance can arise from this.

Floating-point formats can also have [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), where $-0.0$ is different from $+0.0$. The uses of these are niche, but the Wikipedia article does list a few.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-rigorous sort of argument you might use when first learning about fractions to argue that $0$ and $0.0$ are equal in the mathematical sense.

$0.0$ just means $0$ plus the quantity $\frac{0}{10}$, in the same way that $1.1$ means $1$ plus the quantity $\frac{1}{10}$ (commonly written as $1 \frac{1}{10}$ -- a mixed fraction).

So what is the quantity $\frac{0}{10}$?  It's just $0$.  So $0 + \frac{0}{10}$ is just $0 + 0$ which is $0$.

Dian Fishekqiu gave a better worded version of this type of argument in the comments under the question.

Comment: Why do you call that "non-rigorous"?  That's as rigorous as one can get with these types of questions.

Comment: @fleablood I guess I was hoping to fend off potential "that's not a rigorous argument" comments haha.

Comment: It's ... precise.  a.b does mean unevocably a + b/10.  And 0/10 is inarguably 0.  So that's. .... rigorous.

Comment: @fleablood Ok $\text{   }$